# Create multi select check box in SharePoint 2013 Custom User Profile Property?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-property

I need to create a custom user profile property with multi select option.
Can any one help on this.How to create this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a data type supported by the UPSA.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/79930)

Comment: Yes it does. It isn't supported.

Comment: The answer is correct, the review is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider handling it differently. Look at using a Managed Metadata Field. That is how the other multi-value fields are handled, like Skills.